# Locking hash keys to prevent deletion

Tags: perl

Perl v5.8.0 introduced restricted hashes and the `Hash::Util` core module as an interface to that functionality. One of the abilities it mentions is, "the ability to lock an individual key so it cannot be deleted." Nothing in the module appears to offer this functionality, however: neither `lock_keys()` or `lock_values()` prevents keys from being deleted, and `lock_hash()` prevents all keys from deletion and modification.

So how do you lock an individual key so it cannot be deleted?

Comment: You could use a tied hash. This will slow things down. A lot. But no more than using an object instead of a hash.

Comment: Sent an email to the Perl5 maintainers

Comment: So far, the reply is effectively "If you lock the entire hash (so that keys can't be added), and if you lock the value of a element (so that it can't be changed), you can't delete that element."

Comment: From what I can tell there is no way to do what you are asking.  Thus the quoted statement from the docs would be a bug in documentation.  I don't understand why it's there, and so prominent.

Answer (score 2):

The module only provides a means of making an element of a restricted hash both immutable and undeletable.

To achieve the effect you desired, you'd need *magic*, such as a tied hash.

```
package My::Protected::Hash;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp      qw( );
use Tie::Hash qw( );

our @ISA = 'Tie::ExtraHash';

# Usage: tie my %hash, My::Protected::Hash::, LIST
sub TIEHASH  {
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = bless([{}, {}]);
   $self->[1]{$_} = 1 for @_;
   return $self;
}

sub DELETE {
   my ($self, $key) = @_;
   Carp::croak("Can't delete key \"$key\"") if $self->[1]{$key};
   return delete($self->[0]{$key});
}

# Usage: tied(%hash)->lock_key(LIST)
sub lock_key {
   my $self = shift;
   $self->[1]{$_} = 1 for @_;
}

# Usage: tied(%hash)->unlock_key(LIST)
sub unlock_key {
   my $self = shift;
   delete @{ $self->[1] }{@_};
}

1;
```

Example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;

use My::Protected::Hash qw( );

tie my %h, My::Protected::Hash::, "b", "c";
tied(%h)->unlock_key("b");
tied(%h)->lock_key("d");
for my $key (qw( a b c )) {
   if (eval { delete $h{$key}; 1 }) {
      say "Deleted key \"$key\"";
   } else {
      print $@;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Deleted key "a"
Deleted key "b"
Can't delete key "c" at a.pl line 16.
Can't delete key "d" at a.pl line 16.
```

Answer (score 1):

ikegami answer is, of course, a good example of how to achieve the stated goal without using restricted hashes. I'm going to answer my own question based on the information I've uncovered in my research, with assistance from the comments on the original question, focusing on what can and can't be done with restricted hashes. My technical assessment here is based on experimentation and use of `Devel::Peek` to see what the underlying data structures look like.

First, it does seem to be that the `Hash::Util` documentation is misleading. While technically one can lock individual keys so that they can't be deleted, the only way to do this is to also lock them against modification. If you want keys to be mutable but not delible, there is no setting which allows it. You can either use a tie-based solution like ikegami, or work around it using a sub/method which temporarily disables the read-only restriction, updates the value, then makes it read only again.

Restricted hashes work through two tricks: the READONLY flag, and special place-holder values (NULL references) for keys which Perl then treats as "key does not exist". The READONLY flag can be applied to the hash, or to the values in the hash. The `lock_keys()` function manipulates the READONLY flag on the hash; the `lock_value()` function manipulates it on individual values. The `lock_hash()` function simply does both, affecting the hash and all the values in it, so we only need to understand the first two functions to understand the process.

The READONLY flag on the hash itself prevents any keys from being added or removed in the hash. At first glance, this seems to be what I wanted, but there's a wrinkle. The idea with restricted hashes is to limit the set of keys which could appear in the hash, without obliging those keys to be present. As such, you can still delete keys in a READONLY hash, but the deletion is simulated by replacing the current value with one of those special place-holder values I mentioned earlier. From the perspective of the running code, the key is gone, but it's still actually there in the underlying data structure, visible if you use the Dump function from `Devel::Peek`.

The `lock_keys()` function has a couple of variants which deal with keys that already exist versus keys which don't. If you just call `lock_keys(%x)`, you simply apply the READONLY flag to `%x`. If you call `lock_keys(%x, @keys)`, the process is more involved: first, an exception is thrown if `%x` contains any keys not present in `@keys`; then, `%x` is populated with all keys in `@keys` not already present in `%x`; then the READONLY flag is applied; then the keys which were added to `%x` are deleted again, leaving them associated with the "does not exist" place-holder. The `lock_keys_plus()` method simply skips the first of these steps. If the base `lock_keys(%x)` function were the only one available, you'd have to prime your hash with all the permitted keys, lock it, and then delete the entries you didn't want at the time.

The `lock_value()` function is simpler in that it simply applies the READONLY flag to a selected value in the hash. If you do this when the hash itself is not READONLY, you'll get a warning about it being a useless operation. This is not entirely true: the READONLY flag on the value does make the value read-only, it just doesn't protect against the value being deleted from the hash and replaced with a new value that's not read-only. And that brings us to the next point: the READONLY flag on the value protects it against being replaced with that special place-holder which makes it look like the element has been deleted, used when the hash itself is in READONLY mode. Thus, when the hash itself is read-only, values in the hash which are read-only can't be deleted.

Curiously, one thing that the READONLY flag *doesn't* protect against is replacement of a value using the `hv_store()` function. Although this can't add keys to an already-locked hash, it can completely replace a locked value with an unlocked one. I guess if you're hacking around that deep, it's on you to provide your own protection against modifying a locked value, if that's what you want. Note that this also provides a cute way to make an ordinary scalar read-only: use `hv_store()` to alias it into an arbitrary hash, then lock the hash.

Much of this is implementation-dependent, and the `Hash::Util` documentation makes occasional threatening noises about how the implementation may change, but it's been that way from v5.8.0. to v5.30.0 as far as I can tell. New features are present in more recent versions, but I think my description holds across that entire history. Please add comments if you know of any important deviations from what I've said.